# Box-Cox data transformation formulas for one and two-way ANOVA

Tags: anova, likelihood, boxcox-transformation

I want to write my own program with box-cox data transformation for ANOVA. I don't understand how to perform a Maximum Likelihood Estimation of λ for my case. I found out how to find optimal λ for common numeric sequence, but in ANOVA there is several groups (in one-factor case), several factors (in multi-factor case), so Maximum Likelihood Estimation of λ for common numeric sequence doesn't work for data which divided into different groups. Therefore I need to know, is there Box-Cox formulas for ANOVA?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? If it's a programming exercise, fine, but, for actual data analysis, I think there are better alternatives to Box-Cox (e.g. robust regression, quantile regression on untransformed variables).

Comment: @PeterFlom I write a statistical package for the think-tank like R or something, i have already told my boss that in my package must be Box-Cox for anova.

Comment: OK, well, if it has to be in there, then it has to be.  But I'd also put in something for robust regression and quantile reg.  Good luck

Comment: The ANOVA solution is computed with the standard regression formulas, which are the MLE for *iid* Gaussian errors.  How, if at all, does your situation differ from this one?  PS: IMHO @PeterFlom has an idiosyncratic opinion about the utility and appropriateness (or lack thereof) of transformations.  I urge you not to be discouraged by his comments.